# preg_split using PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE with an array of delims

Tags: php, arrays, preg-split

Note: I recently asked this question but it turns out the solution I'm looking for is more advanced than I initially thought.

Using preg_split, how would I split this up, note that the string before the delimiters varies:

```
$string = "big red apple one purple grape some stuff then green apple yatta yatta red cherry green gape";
```

I want to use an array of strings as the delimiters and I want them to be included in the result. Deliminters: [apple, grape, cherry]

My desired output is:

```
Array("big red apple", "one purple grape", "some stuff then green apple", "yatta yatta red cherry", "green grape");
```

Here's what I had originally:

```
$string = "big red apple one purple grape some stuff then green apple yatta yatta red cherry green gape";
$matches = preg_split('(apple|grape|cherry)', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
```

It prints this:
Array ( [0] => big red [1] => one purple [2] => some stuff then green [3] => yatta yatta red [4] => green gape )

without the delimiters.

Comment: Do you have any knowledge of ReGeX (pronounced _re-jek_)? Have you tried _anything_?

Comment: RTLM? http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Comment: possible repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303206/preg-split-how-to-include-the-split-delimiter-in-results-when-using-an-array-of

Answer (score 3):

If you fix the typo of the last word in your input string, then (one possible) pattern is:

```
~(?<=apple|grape|cherry)\s*~
```

This is using [a look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and then splitting on the following whitespace (if it exists). So it also works on the end of the string.

Full example:

```
<?php
/**
 * preg_split using PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE with an array of delims
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/a/16304338/2261774
 */

$string = "big red apple one purple grape some stuff then green apple yatta yatta red cherry green grape";

var_dump(
    preg_split("~(?<=apple|grape|cherry)\s*~", $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
);
```

[See it in action.](http://eval.in/18395)

As you can see I am not using the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` here because I want to have the spaces on which I split removed. Instead the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag is used so that I do not get the (empty) split at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

A bit simpler, with the same result:

```
$string = "big red apple one purple grape some stuff then green apple yatta yatta red cherry green grape";
$re='/\S.*?\s(?:apple|grape|cherry)/';
preg_match_all($re,$string,$m);
var_dump($m[0]);
```